# yield a tuple in a for loop scala

Tags: scala

I would like to extract a tuple with 2 fields from the below code, I know if I yield `(incidentWord)` it works, but I want tuple `(incidentWord, key)`, I mean what ever "key" matched incidentWord. Please advise.

```
val filteredIncidentWords = 
  for (incidentWord <-incs if app_serv_appl.filter(_.length >2).exists(key => incidentWord.contains(key))) yield (incidentWord)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is something like this:

```
val filteredIncidentWords =
  for { incidentWord <-incs
        key <- app_serv_appl.filter(_.length >2)
        if incidentWord.contains(key)
  } yield (incidentWord, key)
```